# Show Taxonomy Name from Slug with ACF Custom Post Type

Tags: php, custom-post-type

How do I return the category name from a custom post type where $area displays the slug? Output looks like this using $area:

> Hotels in north_west

I want the output to look like:

> Hotels in North West

The category is created with this code:

```
$area_filters[tax_query] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'areas',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $area
        )
    );
```

I'm trying to use the get_term_by code. I've tried a number of things in the 'areas' section including 'category', 'area', and some others:

```
    $area_name = get_term_by('name', $area, 'areas');
    global $post;
    $listings_html .= 'Hotels in '.$area_name.';
```

This gives me an error where I call $area_name

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string

Pretty much everything else just gives me a blank with no error

Note: I've spent a couple hours researching to find an answer but no luck. Here are just a few of the links I've reviewed:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16394/how-to-get-a-taxonomy-term-name-by-the-slug

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95502/get-category-id-from-category-slug-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Error is coming because you are trying to echo a Object. Your required value is inside that object.

From above code I believe you have the value `$area = 'north_west'`

If you have this then you have everything, get the area object by following code,

```
// Pretending 'areas' to be taxonomy name
$area_object = get_term_by('slug', $area, 'areas');
```

Now from the object get your name,

```
$area_name = esc_html( $area_object->name );
```

Use `$area_name` where you want to display. Hope this helps.